# Decompressing string (from gzcompress) returns wrong result when special chars are involved

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a front end application in js and I am getting my data (I❤U\n) from a webserver.

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/czmovg26/1/

Webserver:

```
<?php
    print($compressed = base64_encode(gzcompress('I\u2764U\n\uD83D\uDE18\uD83D\uDE18\uD83D\uDE18', 6)));
?>
```

Frontend:

```
var b64Data = "eJzzjCk1MjczCY3Jiyl1sTB2AZKuhha42ABGUQ2i"; // === I❤U\n

// Decode base64 (convert ascii to binary)
var strData = atob(b64Data);
// Convert binary string to character-number array
var charData = strData.split('').map(function (x) {
    return x.charCodeAt(0);
});
// Turn number array into byte-array
var binData = new Uint8Array(charData);
// Pako magic
var data = pako.inflate(binData);
// Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
var decoded = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data));

var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
decoded = decoded.replace(r, function(match, grp) {
  return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16));
});
decoded = unescape(decoded);
```

Now, the string looks the same when you print it in the console, but

```
console.log(decoded == "I❤U\n");
```

resturns false, and things like

```
var val = decoded.replace(RegExp("\n","g"), "<br>");
```

do not work.

The decompression must be the problem, as it works fine with a normal string, but I don't understand, what's wrong with the decompression.

Comment: `console.log(decoded == "I❤U\\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript a string literal with `\n` in it denotes a new line, if you were to log such a string to the console you would see it split along multiple lines.
If you take a look at the log of the decoded string you'd notice its on a single line.

This means your original string did not have a new line in it.
From your php you can see that very clearly. In php the escape slash only escapes the single quote in a single quoted php string, so for `\n` to represent a newline it has to be within a double quoted string.

```
<?php
    print($compressed = base64_encode(gzcompress("I\u2764U\n\uD83D\uDE18\uD83D\uDE18\uD83D\uDE18", 6)));
```